# localhost is not loading while trying to send mail using flask-mail

Tags: flask, flask-mail

The localhost is not running and I am getting an OS:Error of 'No route to host' error when I run the flask app.

I've tried adding this:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

but it does not work.Also I have tried changing the port from 5000 to 4996 and various other ports but still I am facing the same issue .

Here is my complete code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail,Message

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['DEBUG']=True
app.config['TESTING']=False
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT']=456
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL']=True
#app.config['MAIL_DEBUG']=
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']='trvt1234@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']='#insert password here'
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER']='trvt1234@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_MAX_EMAILS']=None
#app.config['MAIL_SUPRESS_SEND']=
app.config['MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS']=False


email = Mail(app)

@app.route('/')
def mail():
   message = Message('Hello',recipients=['trvt1234@gmail.com'])
   email.send(message)
   return('message sent successfully')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I am a newbie to Flask and was figuring out how should I go on about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong `MAIL_PORT` - it should be **465** not 456.